# How to design a pressure regulator test?

Tags: pressure, rocketry

We're designing a pressure regulator test. It is taking an input from an N2 tank at 300 bars, output pressure should be around 70 bars. We are thinking of using 2 pressure transducers, a solenoid to turn on the flow from the tank to the regulator. But we don't have anything downstream from the regulator (except for one of the pressure transducers). What should we place there? And overall, how should we design the test?
Any resources and links would be appreciated.

Comment: a variable load?

Comment: Needle valve. Or something similar to the load, or the actual load.

Comment: Downstream should be a tank with a sensor or gauge (or sufficient hose) with a valve that can act as a variable load. You should test the downstream pressure as you vary upstream pressure and downstream flow rate.

Comment: Would a single safety valve set at 70 bars be sufficient? Since we don't know the performance of the regulator, should we step up the pressure somehow? Any recommendations?

Comment: Safety valve at 70 for what? Doing your test article's job for it?  Test it where a safety valve will not be needed or a safety release that is higher than you expect your regulator to work (if the safety trips, your regulator fails).  Test it through a range of input pressures (300 bar +/- what?) Test it through your range of needed flow rates too! How much 70 bar N2 per second do you need (this is where the variable load comes in)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with this. Yes, we realised that using a relief valve would sort of defeat the purpose. We were thinking instead then of using 2 solenoid valves to to pressurize the regulator and then measure the pressure before and after the regulator.
Also, how could we measure at different flow rates or pressures? We have one N2 tank at 300 bars. What components/setups would you suggest to measure at different pressure and flow rates?